# Why does the map key not retrieve the value that can be plainly seen in the map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure

The following key `:GIC-ID` won't return its value `"999-99-9999"`. I am trying to figure out why.

Here are the keys -- the first row containing column names of a .csv report. The output is formatted to prevent scrolling:

```
["AGY/DIV " "STS" "GIC-ID     " "LAST-NAME      " "FIRST-NAME     " 
"COVERAGE DESCRIPTION                                   " 
"PREMIUM  " "RUN-DATE" "BIL MO "]
```

Here is the data doctored for privacy (output formatted to prevent scrolling):

```
["666/0010" "ACT" "999-99-9999" "MARGE       " "SIMPSON          " 
"YE OLD PILGRIM FAMILY - INSURED                       " 
"0000.00" "123456789" "99999enter code here"]
```

I get the first column containing the keys/column headers and the data created with the following including the zipping together of the column names with what will be each row of data.

```
(def gic-csv-inp (fetch-csv-data "billing_roster.csv"))
(def gic-csv-cols  (first gic-csv-inp))
(def gic-csv-data (rest gic-csv-inp))
(def zm2 (zipmap (map #(keyword %1) gic-csv-cols) (first gic-csv-data)))
```

Now the following keys and data, pulled from a similar but different report, work just fine:

`:Employee_SSN "999-99-9999"`

That is I can extract the value of the key.

There must be something wrong with the keys, and I can certainly correct those, like removing spaces and so on, but I am not sure what is wrong.

Thanks.

### Edit:

The answer to my question is to trim spaces like this:

```
(:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
.
.
.
(def zm2 (zipmap (map #(keyword (cstr/trim %1)) gic-csv-cols) 
(first gic-csv-data)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trimming spaces does work

```
(def zm2 (zipmap (map #(keyword (re-find #"[^\s]*" %1)) gic-csv-cols) (first gic-csv-data)))

=> (zm2 :GIC-ID)
"999-99-9999"
```

[^\s]* being a regexp to match all non-whitespace characters